# How do I return a bit from a stored procedure using nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am using nHibernate in my project but I have a stored procedure which just returns a boolen of success or now.

How do I code this in c#?

I have tried the following but it doesnt like cause I dont have a mapping for bool!!!

> {"No persister for: System.Boolean,
>   mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"}

```
IQuery query = NHibernateSession.CreateSQLQuery("EXEC MyDatabase.dbo.[ContentProvider_Import] :ContentProviderImportLogId", "success", typeof(bool))
                .SetInt32("ContentProviderImportLogId", log.Id);

            var test = query.UniqueResult<bool>();
```

and the same result from

```
IQuery query = NHibernateSession.CreateSQLQuery("EXEC MyDatabase.dbo.[ContentProvider_Import] :ContentProviderImportLogId")
                .AddEntity(typeof(bool))
                .SetInt32("ContentProviderImportLogId", log.Id);

            var test = query.UniqueResult<bool>();
```

Comment: what do you get if you try query.UniqueResult()?

Comment: I don't know hibernate well enough to be sure, but specifying a nullable bool (`bool?`, `Nullable<bool>` or `NHibernateUtil.Boolean`) may do the trick. Also, note that you can edit your question title - you don't have to create a whole new question: click the 'edit' link underneath your question's tags.

Comment: Claudio - it doesnt get that far exception thrown saying above error, or if I try without bool declarations I get a no return type defined exception

Comment: Jeff - I hadnt realised 2nd question had been created my connection die during posting and site "timed out" but it clearly didnt!

Comment: Jeff - NHibernateUtil.Boolean doesnt appear in my intellisense if I do typeof if I dont I get not a type error

Comment: Are you interested in the SP's return value or result set? You're code expects a result set. That won't get a `return 1`. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928847/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-into-nhibernate

Answer (score 5):

I would have tackled this problem in a slightly different way which will hopefully serve as a workaround for you.

I would change my stored procedure to return a bool as follows:

```
declare @result bit
set @result = 1

select @result
```

Then the C# code will be:

```
IQuery query = NHibernateSession.CreateSQLQuery("EXEC MyDatabase.dbo.[ContentProvider_Import] :ContentProviderImportLogId")
                .SetInt32("ContentProviderImportLogId", log.Id);

var test = query.UniqueResult<bool>();
```

Comment: thanks s1mm0t but thats exactly what I've tried, I jsut get an error saying I havent declared the return types

Comment: Not sure what your problem is then. Before I posted my answer, I tried this and it worked fine. I'm running version 2.1.2.4000 of NHibernate are you using an older version? Also, from the way you are calling the SP, it appears that you are using SQLServer which is what I tested against (2008) if you're not, then this could be another reason why it isn't working.

Comment: Sorry following error:

{"Return types of SQL query were not specified [EXEC MyDatabase.dbo.[ContentProvider_Import] :ContentProviderImportLogId]"}

Comment: FYI, if you don't want to declare a variable, you can always cast your select statement like so: SELECT CAST( 1 as BIT )