# Execute stored procedure with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, c#-4.0, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure named "GetListingId" in my database. It takes three string input parameters: `City`, `State`, `PhoneNumber`; one input long parameter: `CallId` and return one output long parameter: `ListingId`.

I'm trying execute it in code:

```
IQuery query = this.appListingRepository.Session.CreateSQLQuery("exec GetListingId @City=:city, @State=:state, @PhoneNumber=:phoneNumber, @CallId=:callId")
                .SetString("city", "SAN JOSE")
                .SetString("state", "CA")
                .SetString("phoneNumber", "+14084801753")
                .SetInt64("callId", 1);

        long id = query.UniqueResult<long>();
```

But this throw exeption: `Invalid column name 'ListingId'`

Stored procedure in SQL Server Managment Studio executed fine.

Stored procedure code:

```
USE [Clickmob_ReportingDb_test]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetListingId]    Script Date: 11/24/2012 10:46:40 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

--CREATE PROCEDURE GetListingId
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetListingId]
(
    @City  varchar(255),
    @State varchar(255),
    @PhoneNumber varchar(255),
    @CallId bigint
)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @TotalPrice float;
  DECLARE @TotalCount float;
  DECLARE @DestNumber varchar(255);
  DECLARE @IsCustD    int;
  DECLARE @Result bigint;

-- Check Duplicated Calls for Listings --------------------------------------------------------------------------

  IF EXISTS (SELECT t.name
             FROM   tempdb.sys.tables t
             WHERE  t.name = '##tmp_acc')
    DROP TABLE ##tmp_acc;

  SELECT Li.AppListingId, Li.ListingInfoId INTO ##tmp_acc
  FROM   CALLS c, USERDATAS ud, LISTINGINFOS Li
  WHERE  c.ReportingUserDataId = ud.UserDataId
  AND    Li.CallId = c.CallId
  AND    c.DateTime > DateAdd(mm,-3,getdate())
  AND    Li.DestinationPhoneNumber = (SELECT TOP 1 ud.PhoneNumber
                                      FROM   CALLS c, USERDATAS ud
                                      WHERE  c.ReportingUserDataId = ud.UserDataId
                                      AND    c.CallId = @CallId);
  SELECT @IsCustD = COUNT(*) FROM ##tmp_acc;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Check Quota Limits -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  IF EXISTS (SELECT t.name
             FROM   tempdb.sys.tables t
             WHERE  t.name = '##tmp_quots')
    DROP TABLE ##tmp_quots;

  SELECT L.ListingId INTO ##tmp_quots
  FROM  (SELECT L.ListingId, L.MonthlyQuotaLimit, L.MonthlyBudget, L.DailyQuotaLimit, L.DailyBudget,
                L.SortingPrice, L.Status, acl.CityId
         FROM   AppLISTINGS L, AppCityToListing acL
         WHERE  L.ListingId=acL.ListingId) AS L
  LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT m.CityId, m.CampaignId, m.AppSubCategoryId, m.AppListingId, m.MonthlyCallEarning, m.MonthlyCallCount,
                ISNULL(d.DailyCallEarning, 0) AS DailyCallEarning, ISNULL(d.DailyCallCount, 0) AS DailyCallCount
         FROM  (SELECT c.CityId, c.CampaignId, Li.AppSubCategoryId, Li.AppListingId,
                       SUM(Li.CallEarning) AS MonthlyCallEarning, COUNT(c.CallId) AS MonthlyCallCount
                FROM   CALLS c, LISTINGINFOS Li
                WHERE  Li.CallId=c.CallId
                AND    Li.CallStatus=1
                AND    YEAR(c.DateTime)=YEAR(getdate())
                AND    MONTH(c.DateTime)=MONTH(getdate())
                GROUP BY c.CityId, c.CampaignId, Li.AppSubCategoryId, Li.AppListingId) AS m
         LEFT JOIN
               (SELECT c.CityId, c.CampaignId, Li.AppSubCategoryId, Li.AppListingId,
                       SUM(Li.CallEarning) AS DailyCallEarning, COUNT(c.CallId) AS DailyCallCount
                FROM   CALLS c, LISTINGINFOS Li
                WHERE  Li.CallId=c.CallId
                AND    Li.CallStatus=1
                AND    YEAR(c.DateTime)=YEAR(getdate())
                AND    MONTH(c.DateTime)=MONTH(getdate())
                AND    DAY(c.DateTime)=DAY(getdate())
                GROUP BY c.CityId, c.CampaignId, Li.AppSubCategoryId, Li.AppListingId) AS d
         ON (m.CityId=d.CityId AND m.CampaignId=d.CampaignId AND m.AppSubCategoryId=d.AppSubCategoryId AND m.AppListingId=d.AppListingId)) AS s
  ON (L.ListingId=s.AppListingId AND L.CityId=s.CityId)
  WHERE L.MonthlyQuotaLimit<=s.MonthlyCallCount
  OR    L.MonthlyBudget<=s.MonthlyCallEarning
  OR    L.DailyQuotaLimit<=s.DailyCallCount
  OR    L.DailyBudget<=s.DailyCallEarning;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Accessible Listings ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  IF EXISTS (SELECT t.name
             FROM   tempdb.sys.tables t
             WHERE  t.name = '##tmp_tbl')
    DROP TABLE ##tmp_tbl;

  SELECT DISTINCT SL.ListingId INTO ##tmp_tbl
  FROM  (SELECT act.CityId
         FROM   AppCities act, AppStates ast
         WHERE  act.StateId=ast.StateId
         AND    UPPER(act.Name)=UPPER(@City)
         AND    UPPER(ast.Name)=UPPER(@State)) AS SC,

        (SELECT aL.ListingId, aLm.MediaId AS ListingMediaId, abm.BrandId, abm.MediaId AS BrandMediaId,
                acm.CustomerId, acm.MediaId AS CustomerMediaId, ascL.SubCategoryId, acL.CityId
         FROM   AppLISTINGS aL, AppCityToListing acL, AppListingToMedia aLm, AppBRANDS ab, AppBrandToMedia abm,
                AppCustomerToMedia acm, AppSubCategoryToListing ascL
         WHERE  aL.ListingId=aLm.ListingId
         AND    aL.ListingId=acL.ListingId
         AND    aL.BrandId=ab.BrandId
         AND    ab.BrandId=abm.BrandId
         AND    ab.CustomerId=acm.CustomerId
         AND    aL.ListingId=ascL.ListingId) AS SL,

        (SELECT m.Number, m.CampaignId, m.MediaId, m.SubCategoryId,
                ISNULL(abc.BrandId, 0) AS ExceptBrandId,
                ISNULL(aLc.ListingId, 0) AS ExceptListingId,
                ISNULL(acc.CustomerId, 0) AS ExceptCustomerId
         FROM  (SELECT ap.Number, ac.CampaignId, ach.MediaId, ascc.SubCategoryId
                FROM   AppPHONENUMBERS ap, AppCAMPAIGNS ac, AppCHANNELS ach, AppSubCategoryToCampaign ascc
                WHERE  ap.CampaignId=ac.CampaignId
                AND    ac.ChannelId=ach.ChannelId
                AND    ap.CampaignId=ascc.CampaignId) AS m
         LEFT JOIN AppBrandToCampaign abc
         ON (m.CampaignId=abc.CampaignId)
         LEFT JOIN AppListingToCampaign aLc
         ON (m.CampaignId=aLc.CampaignId)
         LEFT JOIN AppCustomerToCampaign acc
         ON (m.CampaignId=acc.CampaignId)
         WHERE m.Number=@PhoneNumber) AS SM

  WHERE  SC.CityId=SL.CityId
  AND    SL.SubCategoryId=SM.SubCategoryId
  AND   (SL.ListingMediaId=SM.MediaId
  OR     SL.BrandMediaId=SM.MediaId
  OR     SL.CustomerMediaId=SM.MediaId)
  AND    SL.ListingId <>SM.ExceptListingId
  AND    SL.BrandId <>SM.ExceptBrandId
  AND    SL.CustomerId<>SM.ExceptCustomerId
  AND    SL.ListingId NOT IN (SELECT AppListingId
                              FROM   ##tmp_acc)
  AND    SL.ListingId NOT IN (SELECT ListingId
                              FROM   ##tmp_quots);

  SELECT @Result = COUNT(*) FROM ##tmp_tbl;
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  IF @Result > 0
    BEGIN
      SET @IsCustD = 0;

      SELECT @TotalPrice = SUM(sel.Price)
                           FROM (SELECT aL.ListingId, CASE aL.SortingPrice WHEN 0 THEN aL.LeadPrice
                                                      ELSE aL.SortingPrice END AS Price
                                 FROM   AppListings aL) AS sel, ##tmp_tbl t
                           WHERE sel.ListingId=t.ListingId;

      SELECT @TotalCount = SUM(aL.CallCount)
                           FROM  AppListings aL, ##tmp_tbl t
                           WHERE aL.ListingId=t.ListingId;

      SELECT @Result = (SELECT TOP 1 ISNULL(sel.ListingId, 0) AS ListingId
                        FROM  (SELECT L.ListingId, (L.Price/@TotalPrice - L.CallCount/(@TotalCount+1)) AS Rate
                               FROM  (SELECT aL.ListingId, aL.CallCount, CASE aL.SortingPrice WHEN 0 THEN aL.LeadPrice
                                                                         ELSE aL.SortingPrice END AS Price
                                      FROM   AppListings aL) AS L) AS sel, ##tmp_tbl t
                        WHERE  sel.ListingId=t.ListingId
                        ORDER BY sel.Rate DESC);
    END
  ELSE
    BEGIN
      IF @IsCustD > 0             
        BEGIN
          SET @IsCustD = 1;

          SELECT @TotalPrice = SUM(sel.Price)
                               FROM (SELECT aL.ListingId, CASE aL.SortingPrice WHEN 0 THEN aL.LeadPrice
                                                          ELSE aL.SortingPrice END AS Price
                                     FROM   AppListings aL) AS sel, ##tmp_acc t
                               WHERE sel.ListingId=t.ListingId;

          SELECT @TotalCount = SUM(aL.CallCount)
                               FROM  AppListings aL, ##tmp_acc t
                               WHERE aL.ListingId=t.ListingId;

          SELECT @Result = (SELECT TOP 1 ISNULL(sel.ListingId, 0) AS ListingId
                            FROM  (SELECT L.ListingId, (L.Price/@TotalPrice - L.CallCount/(@TotalCount+1)) AS Rate
                                   FROM  (SELECT aL.ListingId, aL.CallCount, CASE aL.SortingPrice WHEN 0 THEN aL.LeadPrice
                                                                             ELSE aL.SortingPrice END AS Price
                                          FROM   AppListings aL) AS L) AS sel, ##tmp_acc t
                            WHERE  sel.ListingId=t.ListingId
                            ORDER BY sel.Rate DESC);
        END
      ELSE
        RETURN 0;        
    END;            

  UPDATE AppLISTINGS
  SET    CallCount=CallCount+1
  WHERE  ListingId=@Result;

  SELECT @DestNumber = (SELECT TOP 1 ISNULL(n.Number, '') AS Number
                        FROM   AppPHONENUMBERS n
                        WHERE  n.PhoneCallListingId=@Result
                        ORDER BY n.PhoneNumberId);

  INSERT INTO LISTINGINFOS (CallStatus, IsCustomerDuplicate, DestinationPhoneNumber, CallId, AppListingId)
  VALUES (5, @IsCustD, @DestNumber, @CallId, @Result);

  RETURN @Result;
END
```

Comment: Could you share the code for the stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alter your stored procedure to `SELECT @Result` instead of returning it or use ADO.NET as shown in [Rohit's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928847/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-into-nhibernate).

Another approach I've used is to create a wrapper stored proc (GetListintId_return) that selects the result of the GetListingId.